# Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'

Tags: c#

I get this message in my program but i don't know how to fix it i have search on the net but don't find any thing that can help me.

```
private double Price;
private int Count;
private double Vat;

private const double foodVATRate = 0.12, otherVATRate = 0.25;
private decimal Finalprice;
private decimal Rate;

public void Readinput()
{
    Finalprice = (decimal)(Price * Count);
}

private void cal()
{
    char answer = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'))
        Vat = foodVATRate;
    else
        Vat = otherVATRate;

    Rate = Vat * Finalprice;
```

Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal' is what comes up on Rate = Vat * Finalprice; and i don't know i can fix it

Comment: if you have decimal type and want to use it for any calculation just add M after that number 
ex: 1+0.15M

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
Rate = (decimal)Vat * Finalprice;
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to cast one to the other. My guess is that both Price and all of your VAT rates should really be decimal - double isn't (usually) appropriate for dealing with any type of monetary values.

Comment: And a great article explaining why not: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 4):

Change `foodVATRate` to `decimal`, too. There doesn't seem to be any reason for it to be double.

Answer (score 4):

You can't multiply a `decimal` by a `double`. You can fix this by type casting, but you probably just want to stick with using `decimal` for all prices and VAT rates throughout.

The type [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28VS.71%29.aspx) was designed to be useful for financial calculations since it offers high precision at the cost of reduced range for the size of the type in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I used M at the end of decimal number and its work

```
string performance = dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
string sdi = dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    if (Convert.ToDecimal(sdi) >= 1.1M && Convert.ToDecimal(sdi) <= 1.5M)
                        {
                            dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value = 2;
                        }
```